# sql select statement to list companies depending of its members campaign status

Tags: mysql

I have this tables:

Table: company (companyId,...)

Table: members (memberId,company_id,...)

Table: campaigns (campaignId,member_id,status,...)

I want to get a list of all companies, where no members has an active campaign running (status = 1)

Something like this:

```
sql = "SELECT * 
FROM company,members 
WHERE companyId = company_id AND memberId NOT IN 
   (SELECT member_id FROM campaigns WHERE status = 1)"
```

But my problem is that some of the compaies does not have members. This companies should also be listed

I can not get my head around this - can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * from company
WHERE not exists (
    SELECT campaigns.campaignId
    FROM campaigns JOIN members on (members.memberId = campaigns.member_id)
    WHERE STATUS = '1' and members.company_id = company.companyId   
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM company c
LEFT JOIN members m ON c.companyId = company_id
WHERE m.memberID IS NULL OR m.memberId NOT IN (
 SELECT m1.memberId
 FROM members m1 LEFT JOIN campaigns c ON m1.memberId = c.member_id
 WHERE c.status = 1
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
SELECT c.companyId FROM company c LEFT JOIN members m ON
c.companyId = m.company_id INNER JOIN
campaigns cmp ON m.memberId = cmp.member_Id 
WHERE cmp.status NOT IN (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
    SELECT * FROM company,members 
    WHERE companyId = company_id AND 
    (
        memberId NOT IN  (SELECT member_id FROM campaigns WHERE status = 1) 
        OR memberId IS NULL OR memberId = ''
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

This query is like nested for loop it is not good for mush large tables.

select * from company where companyId IN (
select company_id from members where memberId IN (
select member_id from campaigns where status=0 and member_id NOT IN (select member_id from campaigns where status=1)));